# Java Audio Metronome | Timing and Speed Problems

Tags: java, multithreading, audio

I’m starting to work on a music/metronome application in Java and I’m running into some problems with the timing and speed.

For testing purposes I’m trying to play two sine wave tones at the same time at regular intervals, but instead they play in sync for a few beats and then slightly out of sync for a few beats and then back in sync again for a few beats.

From researching good metronome programming, I found that Thread.sleep() is horrible for timing, so I completely avoided that and went with checking System.nanoTime() to determine when the sounds should play.

I’m using AudioSystem’s SourceDataLine for my audio player and I’m using a thread for each tone that constantly polls System.nanoTime() in order to determine when the sound should play. I create a new SourceDataLine and delete the previous one each time a sound plays, because the volume fluctuates if I leave the line open and keep playing sounds on the same line. I create the player before polling nanoTime() so that the player is already created and all it has to do is play the sound when it is time.

In theory this seemed like a good method for getting each sound to play on time, but it’s not working correctly. I’m not sure if the timing problems are from running different threads or if it has to do with deleting and recreating the SourceDataLine or if it’s in playing sounds or what exactly...

At the moment this is just a simple test in Java, but my goal is to create my app on mobile devices (Android, iOS, Windows Phone, etc)...however my current method isn’t even keeping perfect time on a PC, so I’m worried that certain mobile devices with limited resources will have even more timing problems. I will also be adding more sounds to it to create more complex rhythms, so it needs to be able to handle multiple sounds going simultaneously without sounds lagging.

Another problem I’m having is that the max tempo is controlled by the length of the tone since the tones don’t overlap each other. I tried adding additional threads so that every tone that played would get its own thread...but that really screwed up the timing, so I took it out. I would like to have a way to overlap the previous sound to allow for much higher tempos.

Any help getting these timing and speed issues straightened out would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

**SoundTest.java:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class SoundTest implements ActionListener {
static SoundTest soundTest;


// ENABLE/DISABLE SOUNDS
boolean playSound1  = true;
boolean playSound2  = true;


JFrame mainFrame;
JPanel mainContent;
JPanel center;
JButton buttonPlay;

int sampleRate = 44100;
long startTime; 
SourceDataLine line = null; 
int tickLength;
boolean playing = false;

SoundElement sound01;
SoundElement sound02;

public static void main (String[] args) {       
    soundTest = new SoundTest();

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() {
        soundTest.gui_CreateAndShow();
    }});
}

public void gui_CreateAndShow() {
    gui_FrameAndContentPanel();
    gui_AddContent();
}

public void gui_FrameAndContentPanel() {
    mainContent = new JPanel();
    mainContent.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainContent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    mainContent.setOpaque(true);

    mainFrame = new JFrame("Sound Test");               
    mainFrame.setContentPane(mainContent);              
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}

public void gui_AddContent() {
    JPanel center = new JPanel();
    center.setOpaque(true);

    buttonPlay = new JButton("PLAY / STOP");
    buttonPlay.setActionCommand("play");
    buttonPlay.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPlay.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));

    center.add(buttonPlay);
    mainContent.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (!playing) {
        playing = true;

        if (playSound1)
            sound01 = new SoundElement(this, 800, 1);
        if (playSound2)
            sound02 = new SoundElement(this, 1200, 1);

        startTime = System.nanoTime();

        if (playSound1)
            new Thread(sound01).start();
        if (playSound2)
            new Thread(sound02).start();
    }
    else {
        playing = false;
    }
}
}
```

**SoundElement.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class SoundElement implements Runnable {
SoundTest soundTest;


// TEMPO CHANGE
// 750000000=80bpm | 300000000=200bpm | 200000000=300bpm
long nsDelay = 750000000;


int clickLength = 4100; 
byte[] audioFile;
double clickFrequency;
double subdivision;
SourceDataLine line = null;
long audioFilePlay;

public SoundElement(SoundTest soundTestIn, double clickFrequencyIn, double subdivisionIn){
    soundTest = soundTestIn;
    clickFrequency = clickFrequencyIn;
    subdivision = subdivisionIn;
    generateAudioFile();
}

public void generateAudioFile(){
    audioFile = new byte[clickLength * 2];
    double temp;
    short maxSample;

    int p=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < audioFile.length;){
        temp = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * p++ / (soundTest.sampleRate/clickFrequency));
        maxSample = (short) (temp * Short.MAX_VALUE);
        audioFile[i++] = (byte) (maxSample & 0x00ff);           
        audioFile[i++] = (byte) ((maxSample & 0xff00) >>> 8);
    }
}

public void run() {
    createPlayer();
    audioFilePlay = soundTest.startTime + nsDelay;

    while (soundTest.playing){
        if (System.nanoTime() >= audioFilePlay){
            play();
            destroyPlayer();
            createPlayer();
            audioFilePlay += nsDelay;
        }
    }
    try { destroyPlayer(); } catch (Exception e) { }
}

public void createPlayer(){
    AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(soundTest.sampleRate, 16, 1, true, false);
    try {
        line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
        line.open(af);
        line.start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
}

public void play(){
    line.write(audioFile, 0, audioFile.length);
}

public void destroyPlayer(){
    line.drain();
    line.close();
}
}
```

Comment: It's been 6 year, did you solved the problem coz I am stucked with same problem but in Android. If it's solved then how you did it?

Comment: Yes, I solved it. I had asked for help on Java-Gaming and someone there was able to help me get it working. Here is the thread and on post #19 I provided my source code where I got it working:
https://jvm-gaming.org/t/java-audio-metronome-timing-and-speed-problems/49577

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing is difficult to get right. What you have to realise is that in order to even play a sound, it has to be loaded into an audio driver (and possibly a sound card). This takes time, and you have to account for that. There are basically two options for you:

1. Rather than counting down a delay between every beat, count down a delay from the start, when the metronome activates. As an example, say for instance that you want a beat every second. Because of the ~20ms delay, in your old method you'd get beats at 20ms, 1040, 2060, 3080, etc... If you count down from the start and place beats at 1000, 2000, 3000, etc. then they will play at 20ms, 1020, 2020, 3020, etc... There will still be some variance since the dalay itself varies a bit, but there should be about 1000ms between beats and it will not go out of sync (or at least, the problem will not get worse over time and likely can't be heard).
2. The better option, and the one that most of such programs use, is to generate larger pieces of music. Buffer for instance 20 seconds ahead and play that. The timing should be perfect during those 20 seconds. When those 20 seconds are almost over you must generate some new sound. If you can find out how to do this, you should append the new waveform to the old and have it play continuously. Otherwise, just generate a new 20 second soundbit and accept the delay between them.

Now as for your problem with the sounds not being able to overlap... I'm no expert and I don't really know an answer, but this I do know: Something has to mix the sounds if you need them to overlap. Either you can do that yourself in software by combining the waveform bytes (I think it's an addition in some logarithmic space), or you need to send the different overlapping sounds to different 'channels', in which case the audio driver or sound card does it for you. I don't know how this works in Java though, or I forgot, but I learned this through trial-and-error and working with .mod files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ghostkeeper. I had to post a separate answer because it was too long to post as a direct reply to yours.